# Python Flask MongoDB - collection no data

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I got a flask application running in one vagrant box on (192.168.2.100) and an other vagrant box running mongoDB 3.4 on (192.168.2.110).

When i run this python code from my app:

```
mongo_client = MongoClient(mongodb://myuser:mypassword@192.168.2.110/database_local)
g.db = mongo_client.db.database_local

app_users = g.db.app_users

user_id = app_users.insert_one(
    {
        'username': 'user',
        'password': 'password'
    }
).inserted_id
// user_id is created and returned ("592b2c57962d7408027e274d")

// When i run this to verify:
users = g.db.app_users.find()
for user in users:
    print(user['username'])
```

It prints all users inserted...

BUT:

When i ssh into my mongodb and run in mongo console:

```
use database_local
show collections
```

it returns nothing, like the database is empty.

Comment: Shouldn't you use database `app_users` instead of `database_local` when you ssh into the machine?

Comment: hey i edited my source-code, but still the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MongoDB related code looks strange... Try to connect like this:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://myuser:mypassword@192.168.2.110/')  # pass just these options

db = client.database_local  # select database_local database
user_id = db.app_users.insert_one({  # insert into app_users collection
    'username': 'user',
    'password': 'password'
}).inserted_id
```

And then after ssh-ing into your remote machine, select a proper database:

```
use database_local
show collections
```

you should see `app_users` collection with the data you inserted.

[Read more about PyMongo basics here!](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html)